# Add item to nested array of nested object using MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to use the MongoDB C# Driver to add an item to a nested array inside of a BSON document.  I have searched SO, but none of the examples I have found so far match what I am trying to do.

I have a top-level "Organizations" collection in Mongo.  This contains multiple Organization objects with the following structure:

```
{
   "id":"Org1",
   "Name":"First Org",
   "Divisions":[
      {
         "id":"Div1",
         "Name":"First Division",
         "UsersInDivision":[
            "User1",
            "User2"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following POCO classes

```
public class Organization
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
}

public class Division
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> UsersInDivision { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add the string "User3" to the UsersInDivision collection, of Division "Div1" or Organization "Org1".  What is the optimal way to achieve this?  I am trying to use the strongly typed versions of MongoDB data access classes where possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no typed version query for do such a thing, you have to use string based query

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("id", "Org1"), Query.EQ("Divisions.id", "Div1"));
collection.Update(query, Update.AddToSet("Divisions.$.UsersInDivision", "User3"));
```

The reason you cant use strongly typed version is `$` operator.

There is no `$` in current version of mongodb c# driver. [check here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-531)

Comment: collection.Update This is no longer available in current driver

Comment: @Kalanamith Use Builders<TDocument>.Update.AddToSet